# javascript-gadget is not loading in UIwebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

This is sample JavaScript-Gadget Code & how do I load it `UIWebview`

`<script src="//gadgets.example.com/gadgets.jsz?key=keystring" type="text/javascript">`

`</script><script type="text/javascript">`

```
$w(function() {

    BE.gadget.search('#search-example',{

        vvciID:85,
        Mode:true,
        period:3,
        adults:5,
        children:6,
        hybridMode:true,
        hybridOptions:{
            'accom': { tabName:'Stay', adults:3 },
            'events':{ tabName:'Play', adults:4 }
        },
        minDaysFromToday:10,
        searchLocation:'./11-gadget.html'
    });
});
```

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: 1). make a javascript and add the function. 2) call the html page which contains the js. :)

Comment: hello all, i just want to make visible gadget and get interaction in Iphone by calling Html page (and Javascript) in UIWebView but is not allowing me to do. Not even in Safari. (Safari gives me an error : Not Supported URL).
thanks for reply guys.

Comment: Gadget is not supported in Iphone as Flash Files.

Comment: your 'scr=' tag look illegal. Did you forget to add 'http:'?

Comment: can you right more about what are you trying to do and how you are doing it?

Comment: Please, use http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/ as a tutorial to show a html from your machine using file:// for the url. Then make sure not to start the gadget url with protocol less //, but use http:// instead (those two cannot be combined) and then add the script to the html page and call it on the onload() function.